# Getting Warning: include(Mage/Pay/Model/Pay.php): in custom payment method

Tags: magento-1.9, payment, payment-methods

I've followed the following tutorial (part one and two) http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-payment-method-module-in-magento-part-one--cms-23464

The payment is appearing correctly in the cms, but when I try using it on the website it doesn't appear. The system.log gives me the following error:

> 2015-09-28T14:06:36+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Pay/Model/Pay.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
>   2015-09-28T14:06:36+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Pay/Model/Pay.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/community:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/core:/var/www/html/magento/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

Even though there is no mention of the  Pay model anywhere in the config files, only my custom model which is paymentmethod..

What am I missing or doing wrong?

**Edit**: config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Foomobi_Foopayment>
      <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    </Foomobi_Foopayment>
  </modules>

  <global>     
    <helpers>
      <foopayment>
        <class>Foomobi_Foopayment_Helper</class>
      </foopayment>
    </helpers>

    <blocks>
      <foopayment>
        <class>Foomobi_Foopayment_Block</class>
      </foopayment>
    </blocks>

    <models>
      <foopayment>
        <class>Foomobi_Foopayment_Model</class>
      </foopayment>
    </models>

  </global>

  <default>
    <payment>
      <foopayment>
        <active>1</active>
        <model>foopayment/foopayment</model>
        <order_status>pending</order_status>
        <title>CustomPaymentMethod</title>
        <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
        <payment_action>sale</payment_action>
      </foopayment>
    </payment>
  </default>

  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <foopayment>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>Foomobi_Foopayment</module>
          <frontName>foopayment</frontName>
        </args>
      </foopayment>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: can you post in the question the `config.xml` of the module you created?

Comment: @Marius Sure thing. Done.

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with `Mage/Pay/Model/Pay.php`. are you sure this module is the problem?

Comment: That's what making me so confused. I suppose the error could be coming from another module, but then why won't my custom payment method show up on the website?

Comment: It seems I need to clear the cache. Which is weird because I've done that already before.. :/

Comment: i am agree with @Marius.It may be  other payment module issue...Better idea to  disable this module.. and check again. Is error created or not